# looping through multiple arrays in JQuery from a multi array JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Am I on the wrong path here?

I have a ajax call to upload some files.

I then create a array on the PHP side and send it back as JSON. But im not sure if the JSON format is correct.

Problem is I want to populate a dataTable with the returned JSON data, but I having difficulty reading the data. If its a single file then its fine and it works, but as soon as its more than one file

**PHP CODE**

> ```
>         $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE uuid = :id");
>         $stmt->execute(array(":id" => $id));
>         $row = $stmt->fetch();
>         $json = array();
>
>         $json[] = $row;
>         echo json_encode($json);
> ```

**on the JQuery/AJAX call side**

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>     $('#myfiles').on("change", function() {
>         var myfiles = document.getElementById("myfiles");
>         var files = myfiles.files;
>         var data = new FormData();
>
>         for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
>             data.append('file' + i, files[i]);
>         }
>
>         $.ajax({
>             url: './inc/MediaScripts.php',
>             type: 'POST',
>             contentType: false,
>             data: data,
>             processData: false,
>             cache: false
>         }).done(function(html) {
>
>             var t = $('#vidlib_dtable').DataTable();
>             var obj = eval(html);
>             $.each(obj, function(key,value) {
>                 t.row.add( [
>                     value.name,
>                     value.title,
>                     value.path,
>                     value.duration,
>                     value.uploaded_date,
>                     value.uploaded_by,
>                     value.keyword,
>                     value.comment,
>                 ] ).draw();
>             });
>
>         });
>     });
> });
> ```

*The original return has more columns, hence the above columns in the dataTable add.*

The return looks like multiple (singular) JSON arrays.

> [{"uuid":"236","name":"Koala.jpg"}]
>   [{"uuid":"237","name":"Lighthouse.jpg"}]

I was wondering if it should not take the shape of something like this

> [{"uuid":"236","name":"Koala.jpg"}, {"uuid":"237","name":"Lighthouse.jpg"}]

If the format that I receive the data in is fine, how do I go about looping trhough the multiple arrays on the JQuery side?

Comment: It should be an array of objects -> `array[object{}, object{}, object{}, ...etc]` (*your second example*) (Allowing you to iterate it correctly :-) ). Not `array[object{}] array[object{}]`

Comment: @darren thanks, but how do i structure that on the php side. Is the php calle multiple times (per file), or the the AJAX call to php on multi files handled in one go?

Comment: That depends how you upload them (*you're uploading them right?*). Can users upload multiple files at once or do they do it one at a time?

Comment: you can select more than one file at anyone time to upload.
I just put an `die(print_r($json));` before the `echo` in php and saw that it returns one array at a time. Does AJAX then wait for the 'completion' of the expected data to be returned?

Comment: maybe the `.done()` can be something else to handle each returned array on its own?

Comment: Are you trying to put the data into the datatable as the files are uploaded? Sort of like a live feed?

Comment: yes. that bit works fine. copying the files over from the phpTMP folder to the picture folder and adding a record for each file in the database. Its only on returning to JQuery that I want to populate the newly added records to the dataTable.

Comment: Why not try this - Run the ajax to upload the files and when its done you use the `.done()` and run the ajax request to get the `json` data you require instead of trying to do it as it happens?

Comment: Thanks for the replies Darren, but Zander Rootman has hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Perfectly alright boet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are echo'ing 3 different JSON object arrays.
Each time your loop iterates you echo, the loop then re-creates the array and echo's the new JSON array.

```
$json = array();
//forloop{ START
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE uuid = :id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":id" => $id));
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    array_push($json, $row);
//} END
echo json_encode($json);
```

Initialize your array before the loop, and echo it after it's been fully created.

Comment: indeed. simple solution or just me looking so hard at the problem and not seeing the bigger picture. @Zander Rootman thanks.